# gsutil + rsync remove synced files? (no --remove-source-files flag?)

Tags: gsutil

Is there a way to make `gsutil rsync` remove synced files?

As far as I know, normally it is done by passing `--remove-source-files`, but it does not seem to be an option with `gsutil rsync` ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)).

---

**Context:**
I have a script that produces a large amount of CSV files (100GB+) I want those files to be transferred to Cloud Storage (and once transferred to be removed from my HDD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/).

Per documentation:

> Local storage: Objects that are new or modified will be stored in
>   their entirety in a local temporary file **until they are closed or
>   synced.**

Answer (score 0):

One work-around for small buckets is delete all bucket contents and re-sync periodically.